# Javascript string comparison not working, searched a lot?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code (it's a bookmarklet)

```
    javascript:(function(){
    a=document.createElement('script');
    a.setAttribute('src','//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    data='[["#txtapplicantlname","agrawal","text"],["#txtapplicantfname","aayush","text"],["#txtfather","Ranjan","text"],["#txtmother","Neelam","text"],["#txtPincode","452010","text"],["#txtPhone","2147483647","text"],["#txtEmail","aayush@mail.com","text"]]';
    for(a=$.parseJSON(data),b=a.length-1;0<=b;b--){
        c=a[b];
        if (c[2] == 'text') {
            console.log(c);
            $(c[0]).val(c[1]);
    }
    }
})();
```

It used to work fine until I inserted the `if` statement, then it broke. The console doesn't give me any errors and I have googled a lot for javascript string comparison errors and found nothing useful.

I tried to use `equals` and `compareTo` and ended up with console errors and nothing working.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'equals' of undefined fillform.php:1

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'compareTo' of undefined
```

Help is highly appreciated.

Note: The variables are named like that for a reason, it being that it was initially compiled with Google closure compiler and the `if` statement is being edited in.

Comment: Note: Slightly edited, made a typing mistake making c[2] into c[3], fixed. Code is still broken though

Comment: check the type of `c` and `c[3]` using `jQuery.type()` function

Comment: sidenote: why do you wrap `data` in a string just to JSON.parse it in the next line? simply remove the quotes and the JSON.parse call!

Comment: The data variable is inserted dynamically via php. This is because the bookmarklet cannot make ajax calls on https websites. The current value of data is merely a prototype

Comment: For some weird reason, the query does indeed console log c, but doesnt actually do the jquery action of filling it out.

Comment: Its not good to edit Google closures generated code!

Comment: Does the element with selector `c[0]` exist? Maybe a typo?

Comment: I dont know why or how it happened, but i pressed F12 on iexplore to check the console and clicked it again, and it worked 0.0. Guess some things i will never understand..

Comment: If that's the case, consider deleting this question then; if not, it will get closed automatically as too localized :)

Comment: It may sometimes work as you have discovered, but it is indeterminate based on the asynchronous script load. (My answer explains this.) Please see/accept my answer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with this code; string comparison is not one of them.

1) You aren't waiting for the asynchronously loaded script to complete. This code should pretty much always fail because `$.parseJSON()` isn't available. In fact, once I fixed that problem, this code works fine for me:

```
    (function(){
        a=document.createElement('script');
        a.setAttribute('src','//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js');

        var afterJqueryLoad = function() {
            data='[["#txtapplicantlname","agrawal","text"],["#txtapplicantfname","aayush","text"],["#txtfather","Ranjan","text"],["#txtmother","Neelam","text"],["#txtPincode","452010","text"],["#txtPhone","2147483647","text"],["#txtEmail","aayush@mail.com","text"]]';
            for(a=$.parseJSON(data),b=a.length-1;0<=b;b--){
                c=a[b];
                if (c[2] == 'text') {
                    console.log(c);
                    $(c[0]).val(c[1]);
                }
            }
        };

        var jqueryReady = false;
        a.onreadystatechange= function () {
            if((this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') && !jqueryReady) {
                jqueryReady = true;
                afterJqueryLoad();
            }
        };

        a.onload = function() {
            if(!jqueryReady) {
                jqueryReady = true;
                afterJqueryLoad();
            }
        };
        document.body.appendChild(a);
    })();
```

2) Use better var names (a, b, and c are not good var names).

3) Use `var` to scope vars correctly. Right now your code is shadowing globals and stomping on vars even within the same scope; the `a` var, for example, would stomp on your script elem var. (You should still change the var names per (2) but using `var` is not optional; you must always do this to scope vars correctly.)

4) Use spaces to help readability; your `for` line is unnecessarily difficult to read having no spaces.

All together now:

```
(function(){
    var jqueryScriptElem = document.createElement('script');
    jqueryScriptElem.setAttribute('src', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js');

    var afterJqueryLoad = function() {
        var data = '[["#txtapplicantlname","agrawal","text"],["#txtapplicantfname","aayush","text"],["#txtfather","Ranjan","text"],["#txtmother","Neelam","text"],["#txtPincode","452010","text"],["#txtPhone","2147483647","text"],["#txtEmail","aayush@mail.com","text"]]',
            dataParsed = $.parseJSON(data);
        for(var dataItemIndex = dataParsed.length - 1; 0 <= dataItemIndex; dataItemIndex--) {
            var dataItem = dataParsed[dataItemIndex];
            if (dataItem[2] == 'text') {
                console.log(dataItem);
                $(dataItem[0]).val(dataItem[1]);
            }
        }
    };

    var jqueryReady = false;
    jqueryScriptElem.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if((this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') && !jqueryReady) {
            jqueryReady = true;
            afterJqueryLoad();
        }
    };

    jqueryScriptElem.onload = function() {
        if(!jqueryReady) {
            jqueryReady = true;
            afterJqueryLoad();
        }
    };
    document.body.appendChild(jqueryScriptElem);
})();
```